# Как сделать, чтобы бот отвечал на текстовые сообщения Inline кнопками?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, telebot

Мне надо отправить боту, например, название города, а он чтобы в ответ присылал мне для каждого города свое меню с Inline кнопками и т.д.
Мне подсказали пример кода:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKKEN') #здесь должен быть токкен вашего бота

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'menu'])
def Welcom(message):
 mesg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}. Введите Ваш город")
 bot.register_next_step_handler(mesg, city) #здесь бот ждёт пока пользователь введёт что либо в чат
 
def city(message):
  if message.text == 'Москва': #здесь мы указываем то что должен ввести пользователь
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Москва ваш город') #если пользователь ввёл нужное слово или фразу то бот отправит это сообщение
  else:
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мне не удалось ничего найти') #если пользователь ввел что-то не то бот отправит это сообщение 
 
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

и сказали, что чтобы Inline кнопки в ответ добавить, их нужно прописать после "if message.text == 'Москва':" , я это делаю, выглядит это вот так:

```
    def city(message):
  if message.text == 'Москва':
      markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
      button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 1', callback_data='1')
      button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 2', callback_data='2')
      markup.row(button1)
      markup.row(button2)
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Москва ваш город')
  else:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Мне не удалось ничего найти')
```

но после запуска бота кнопки все равно не отображаются. Что мне делать и как вывести Inline кнопки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же не отправляете кнопки даже

```
if message.text == 'Москва':
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 1', callback_data='1')
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка 2', callback_data='2')
    markup.row(button1)
    markup.row(button2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Москва ваш город', reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: АААА БЛИН ТОЧНО, СПАСИБИЩЕ

Answer (score -2):

вы не выводите кнопки на экран, стоит воспользоваться`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Москва ваш город', reply_markup=markup)`

Comment: А в уже принятом ответе говорится не о том же самом?